# F# Writing custom foldback function for list

Tags: list, recursion, f#, pattern-matching

I am learning F#. I have written custom fold function for list (with help here on StackOverflow). I am now trying to write foldback function say myOwnFoldBack. The expected output might be `myOwnFoldBack (+) 0 [1; 2; 3 ]` should return `6`.

Here is my code for myOwnFold

```
let rec myOwnFoldf s0 =
  function
  | [] -> s0
  | x::tail -> myOwnFoldf (f s0 x) tail
```

This works fine. 
Here is code for myOwnFoldBack

```
let rec myOwnFoldBack  f s0 =
  function
  | [] -> 0
  | x::tail -> x f (myOwnFoldBackf tail)
```

The error I get is:

```
Type mismatch. Expecting a
    'a    
but given a
    ('b -> 'a -> int) list -> int    
The resulting type would be infinite when unifying ''a' and '('b -> 'a -> int) list -> int'
```

Comment: looks like you have a small typo, second `myOwnFoldBack` is `myOwnFoldBackf`

Comment: I think apart from that, there are some more problems.

Comment: There seem to be a few more. `myOwnFoldBackf` is returning 0 isntead of `s0` in case of empty list, and in the other case you're applying `x` to `f` and you're not passing `s0` to the recursive call...

Comment: @HonzaBrestan can you please write the correct version. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured it out finally!

```
let rec myOwnFoldBack  f s0 =
  function
  | [] -> s0
  | x::tail ->    f  x (myOwnFoldBack f s0 tail)
```